# best approach to analyze text in PHP?

Tags: php, user-input, analyzer

I need to analyze a users' post and categorize it. For example: I have to categorize every post as a "buy" post or a "sell" post based on the text - "I'm looking to **sell** my house" is categorized as "sell". The problem is that often its not so simple - "I'm looking to get rid of my old house" also needs to be categorized as "sell". "I'm looking for a house" becomes "buy". I also would like to categorize these posts based on the item in question - for example, the post above would be categorized as "buy" and as "house".

Can anyone recommend a good approach / good framework / technique when it comes to analyzing and understanding user input? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why not include a buy / sell radio button combo?

Comment: As I said, I need not only buy/sell but also what type of item it is.
I could add radio buttons and dropdown lists, but I wanted something more clever.
Maybe as a fallback if the system didn't understand what the guy wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right; it's a hard thing to do.

Yahoo! has a [Term Extraction](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V2/termExtraction.html) API/Web service you can use. It's a pretty good way to use language analysis on your own text without writing a million lines of code to do it yourself. I haven't used it, so I've no idea how well it works with similar meanings, as your question asks.

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is basically a [Bayesian filtering problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering), also used for spam filtering. See also [this talk](http://www.paulgraham.com/better.html). It's a reasonably complicated area.